# GRUB 2 submenu default option

Tags: arch-linux, grub

I can find plenty of information on how to change GRUB2 default boot option but not really much on changing default/order within a submenu.

I would like Windows to remain as my default boot option within Grub however I have a seperate Arch install with two kernels.  Right now the linux-lts kernel is the default option such that when I select the "Arch Linux" top-level option it boots linux-lts.  Can I change this to boot linux without making the specific kernel a top-level item?

Comment: For anyone else I have found a related issue with a recent patch that is waiting to be approved: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/28081

Comment: I can confirm applying the patch to /usr/share/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib and re-running grub-mkconfig has solved my issue.